# PostgreSQL vs Postgres Plus

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know what substantial differences there are between the [regular PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org) and [Postgres Plus](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus.do)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The database is the same, meaning that the SQL is fully compatible to any other PostgreSQL installation around (save for the GIS data formats).

The main difference is that there is a bunch of modules and tools bundled with Postgres Plus that you would have to collect and install separately and by yourself otherwise. Thus the main advantage is easy and speedy installation.

Most of the bundled stuff looks like it's freely available from other sources. That Postgres Studio application looks suspiciously close to pgAdmin III.

Comment: Given that the main developer of pgAdmin3 works for EDB the similarity is not a coincidence.

Answer (score 14):

One important difference is the licence:
Postgres Plus is only free for "non-production" use. 
you can find detailed purchasing options here:
  http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/purchase.do

Answer (score 7):

Postgres PLUS is proprietary,  PostgreSQL is Open source under permissive license (and that's why Postgres PLUS is proprietary).

Postgres PLUS has support for Oracle PL/SQL, while PostgreSQL does not, at least not officially.

Those are two most obvious differences.

Answer (score 3):

I used 8.2 and when was the time to switch to 8.3 I tried PostGresPlus.

The Speed was a lot **faster**. LOT I mean queries that took 30 secs, takes now less than 2 seconds. I am not sure if it's 8.3 that is faster or the Enterprise Plus but I can tell you that I was impressed.

Other thing that I like is that I can **debug** proc stored. It cames with more tools.

Comment: What sort of queries.  Was it a transactional application, a data warehouse, a report off an operational system?

Comment: I've never used the Plus distibution but the difference in performance probably comes from the different default configuration - the default configuration for the "community" version has always been somewhat conservative (less recently).

Comment: PostgreSQL has minimalistic default configuration - with low shared_buffers and low work_mem. PostgreSQL Plus has these higher these values. Next - there was a significant speedup between 8.2 and 8.3 - PostgresPlus uses same engine as PostgreSQL so there should not be different performance with same configuration.

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.3 can easily be 10X as fast as PostgreSQL 8.2 on common workloads.  Perhaps some of the speedup you saw came from something specific to Postgres Plus, but you would have to compare community PostgreSQL 8.3 vs. Postgres Plus 8.3 to be sure.  The only thing you learned so far for sure is that all 8.3 variations of PostgreSQL are faster than all 8.2 variations.