# Develop with Postgres Plus and Deploy Postgresql Open Source?

Tags: postgresql, enterprisedb

According to the answers in [this comparison question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344038/postgresql-vs-postgres-plus), there's no technical difference between the core PostgreSQL engine and Postgres Plus server from EnterpriseDB. The developer license is only [$95/seat](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/purchase.do).

Their [development tools](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus/overview.do) look quite attractive and that cost might be worth it to get increased productivity even if you then deploy the open source version. Has anyone tried this and run into problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only development tools I see there look [an awful lot](http://www.enterprisedb.com/images/common/pgadmin_III_screen_shot.PNG) like [pgadmin III](http://www.pgadmin.org/screenshots/), which is free software (both in terms of money and freedom).

Were there other development tools you were referring to?

Comment: there may be a difference between "looks like" and actually being the same as the open source release of pgadmin III - hence my question :-)

Comment: I have not used their development tools, but I find it highly unlikely that they are anything other than exactly the same as the open source release of pgadmin III. I suspect you'd be paying $95 for a slightly more convenient install.